# cannot perform reduce with flexible type error in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I  have a dataset of 4 attributes like:

```
  taxi id   date time   longitude   latitude
0   1   2/2/2008 15:36  116.51  39.92
1   1   2/2/2008 15:46  116.51  39.93
2   1   2/2/2008 15:56  116.51  39.91
3   1   2/2/2008 16:06  116.47  39.91
4   1   2/2/2008 16:16  116.47  39.92
```

datatype of each attribute is as follows:

```
taxi id    dtype('int64')
date time  dtype('O')
longitude   dtype('float64')
latitude    dtype('float64')
```

i want to calculate mean and standard deviation (std) for each attribute.

For mean i have tried this code:

```
np.mean('longitude')
```

but it gives me error like:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify that you're looking for the mean of your dataframe. As it is, you're not referencing your dataframe at all when you call `numpy.mean()`.

If you dataframe is called `df`, using `pandas.Series.mean` should work, like this:

```
df['longitude'].mean()
df['longitude'].std()
```

As it is, you're calling `numpy.mean()` on a string, which doesn't mean much. If you really wanted to use `numpy.mean()`, you could use `np.mean(df['longitude'])`

Answer (score 2):

You can using `pandas` `describe`

```
df.describe()
Out[878]: 
           taxi   id   longitude   latitude
count  5.000000  5.0    5.000000   5.000000
mean   2.000000  1.0  116.494000  39.918000
std    1.581139  0.0    0.021909   0.008367
min    0.000000  1.0  116.470000  39.910000
25%    1.000000  1.0  116.470000  39.910000
50%    2.000000  1.0  116.510000  39.920000
75%    3.000000  1.0  116.510000  39.920000
max    4.000000  1.0  116.510000  39.930000
```